# How to correctly target data from spotify API?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am trying to get the artist's name to appear on an overlay I have created, how do I target the code correctly to access this? As,  data.artist[0].name is not working?

```
// Get the Album Information from the API to show on the overlay

    function albumInformation(data){

    var infoHTML = '<ul id="data">';

    $.each(data.tracks, function(i, data){
      infoHTML += '<li class="albumInfo">';
      infoHTML += '<p' + data.artist[0].name + '"></p>';
      infoHTML += '</li>';
    }); // closes each

    infoHTML += '</ul>';

  $.getJSON(spotifyURL, albumData, albumInformation);

      $(lightboxOverlay).append(infoHTML);
```

Spotify API Information

```
{
  "tracks" : [ {
    "album" : {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" :    
        "https://open.spotify.com/artist/3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2",
        "id" : "3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2",
        "name" : "The Beatles",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2"
      } ],
      "available_markets" : [ "CA", "MX", "US" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/0ETFjACtuP2ADo6LFhL6HN"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0ETFjACtuP2ADo6LFhL6HN",
      "id" : "0ETFjACtuP2ADo6LFhL6HN",
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the the `album` level of the data. To access artist's name from the payload you would need the following:

```
data.tracks[0].album.artists[0].name;
```

So in the context of your `$.each` code it would be:

```
 $.each(data.tracks, function(i, track){
   infoHTML += '<li class="albumInfo">';
   infoHTML += '<p' + track.album.artists[0].name + '"></p>';
   infoHTML += '</li>';
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I can not get the data to show.  The console is showing:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: what's the result of `data.tracks[0].album`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/90s15v35/1/  I am not having much luck with this one.  I can get the album images to show with  html += '<img src="' + eachAlbum.album.images[0].url + '">';

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/90s15v35/1/  if you have time to help here is a fiddle.  Thank you.